# Specified procedure couldn't be found

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I have installed Pytorch but when I run it , it gives the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I have only tried and imported it like this:

```
import torchvision
```

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch is an open source machine learning framework.Torchvision is part of the PyTorch project.

First,you need install torch.

Second,install torchvision.

You can use this command:

```
pip install torch===1.7.1 torchvision===0.8.2 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This command can install torch and torchvision at the same time.

Please refer here:https://pytorch.org/